# PHP float add regex add spaces and comma

Tags: php, regex

My `$customer_entry['earnings']` = `3521793.36`

I need add a regex, that this variable has been: `3 521 793,36`

Comment: What makes you think that you need a regex for this?

Comment: `number_format()` will do the job

Comment: @maio290, because I know how to write a regex for this in javascript: `.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ' ')
                    .replace('.', ',');`

Comment: Now you only need to explain why you don't just use the same regex in php then.

Answer (score 1):

A lot easier to understand using the PHP builtin function `number_format`.

```
$value = 3521793.36;
echo number_format($value,2,',',' ');
```

Which results in

> 3 521 793,36